# MonoRail redirect to # anchor

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, castle-monorail

I'm using [Castle Monorail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/) with [jQuery tabbed navigation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs).

When handling a controller action, I would like to redirect to a view, and control which tab is visible. Therefore, I'd like to have my controller redirecting to a specific anchor in a view, something along the lines of:

```
RedirectToAction("Edit", "id=1", "#roles"));
```

Resulting in the url:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/User/edit.rails?id=1#roles
```

However, the actual result encodes the **#** sign to **%23**

```
http://localhost/MyApp/User/edit.rails?id=1&%23roles=&
```

I'm surely missing a basic concept here. What do I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not only encode the '#' sign, it simply refer to it as another query string parameter (adds '&' and '=')

I'd advise you to post this question to the [users group of Castle Project](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users), and even better - open issue on [Castle's issue tracker](http://support.castleproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I used RedirectToUrl() and used a static url.

Another solution would be to use the Routing-engine and create the url yourself, and then add the actual hash.

check

RoutingModuleEx.Engine.CreateUrl()

Or something like that.